# How do I exempt GKE `system:*` principals from Admin Read (Data Access) Audit logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to see audit log of read operations against Kubernetes API server, but only for principals in our organization and exclude the `system:*` users from generating Admin Read logs.

However, I can't add `system:*` principal in Exempted principals settings of Audit log: [image]

Is there a way how to avoid logging excessive Admin Read information caused by GKE system accounts?

Comment: Why are you trying to specify `system/*`. That is not a valid domain, group, or user principal.

Comment: It is because these principals (which are kubernetes accounts) generate 99% of logs that I don't want to have. I filter it out in Logs Explorer with this query 

`resource.type="k8s_cluster" AND
(log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity") OR log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access") OR log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/system_event") OR log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/policy")) protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail!~"system:.*"``

I would like to avoid ingesting these logs because it generates unnecessary charges.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add ‘system:*’ as a principal in the Exempted principals settings of Audit log due to the fact that PRINCIPAL refers to a user for whom Data Access audit logs aren't collected. This depends on the [Binding type members](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Binding#FIELDS.members), which describes various , including users and groups, but not variables or syntax  that  can be used to configure Data Access audit logs. Check from where these system logs are generated like   service account, username, or domain names generating the system logs,  configure them using the  [AuditConfig objects](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access?&_ga=2.193056173.1241696505.1704595893-152414197.1702990283&_gac=1.116371572.1703832505.Cj0KCQiA1rSsBhDHARIsANB4EJaViA67Qex5LHaS7dBCWkW4an3aIp3h56JFC3zAfj4sAXBNJbTlZc8aAq9eEALw_wcB#auditconfig_objects) . You can also follow this official doc to [Enable or disable the Configure Data Access audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access?&_ga=2.193056173.1241696505.1704595893-152414197.1702990283&_gac=1.116371572.1703832505.Cj0KCQiA1rSsBhDHARIsANB4EJaViA67Qex5LHaS7dBCWkW4an3aIp3h56JFC3zAfj4sAXBNJbTlZc8aAq9eEALw_wcB#config-console) with the Google Cloud console.

**EDIT-1** : As per the official documentation on [system event audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#system-event) are

> generated by Google systems; they aren't driven by direct user action.
> System Event audit logs are always written; **you can't configure,
> exclude, or disable them**.

One of the possible ways to exclude this system audit logs is by using [exclusion filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions).

> you can set multiple exclusion filters. **Exclusion filters let you
> exclude matching log entries from being routed to the sink's
> destination or from being stored in a log bucket**. You create exclusion
> filters by using the Logging query language. **Excluded log entries
> aren't available in the Logs Explorer**.

Comment: Thank you so maybe a follow up question - how can I reduce the audit log ingestion rate, produced by system accounts? Is the answer basically "you can't" and I have to pay for logs that I have no use of?

Comment: @phandox : Please check **Edit-1** for more information.